# Problem connecting to Firebird 3 embedded with C# in .NET

Tags: c#, sql, database, firebird, firebird-embedded

I am trying to connect to Firebird 3 embedded database from a .NET project. I have copied all the files of Firebird to the executing directory of the application. I have used the following connection string builder:

```
            var builder = new FbConnectionStringBuilder()
            {
                UserID = v1,
                Password = v2,
                Database = v3,
                ServerType = FbServerType.Embedded,
                Charset = "UTF8",
                ClientLibrary = "fbclient.dll" 
            };
```

However I get the following connection error

> FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbException (0x80004005):
>   Unable to complete network request to host "xnet://Global\FIREBIRD".
>
> Unable to complete network request to host "xnet://Global\FIREBIRD".
>
> at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionInternal.Connect()
>   at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionPoolManager.Pool.CreateNewConnectionIfPossibleImpl(FbConnectionString connectionString)
>   at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionPoolManager.Pool.GetConnection(FbConnection owner)
>   at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnection.Open()
>   at DZApp.LoginForm.CheckPassword(String v1, String v2, String v3) in C:\Users\DZ\Desktop\DZApp\DZApp\LoginForm.cs:line 89

I know that the password is not necessary and have removed it but it doesn't work, what could be the problem?

Answer (score 3):

I am able to reproduce this error with a simple application when it **does not** use the fbclient.dll with access to Firebird Embedded, but instead loads a fbclient.dll on the search path (eg in C:\Windows\System32 or C:\Windows\SysWoW64 if the application is 32 bits).

In that mode, fbclient tries to establish a 'local' connection to a Firebird instance through the XNET protocol (that is through `xnet://Global\FIREBIRD`). When no Firebird is running, this then fails.

In my attempts to reproduce this, I have found the following conditions can trigger this:

- Only `fbclient.dll` is deployed in the folder of the application **without** the rest of Firebird Embedded:

  fbclient attempts to create a local connection through XNET, which fails.
- The embedded engine (`engine12.dll`) is not present or in the wrong location. If `fbclient.dll` is at `C:\path\to\firebird\fbclient.dll`, then `engine12.dll` should be at `C:\path\to\firebird\plugins\engine12.dll`

  fbclient attempts to create a local connection through XNET, which fails.

  This is an explicit example of the previous item.
- `fbclient.dll` is **not** deployed  in the folder of the application:

  fbclient on the path (eg in Windows\System32 or SysWoW64) is used instead, which attempts to create a local connection through XNET, which fails.

  This case will trigger a `DllNotFoundException` instead when there is no `fbclient.dll` of the appropriate bitness on the path.
- `fbclient.dll` + Firebird embedded have different bitness from application (eg x86 or AnyCPU application with a 64 bit Firebird, or a x64 application with a 32 bit Firebird)

  fbclient with appropriate bitness on the path (eg in Windows\System32 or SysWoW64) is used instead, which attempts to create a local connection through XNET, which fails.

  This case may trigger a `BadImageFormatException` instead when there is no `fbclient.dll` of the appropriate bitness on the path.

As an aside: under these conditions, if a Firebird instance is running, it will result in an error *"connection lost to database"* instead, probably because the Firebird ADO.net Provider does not supply a password as Firebird Embedded does not need it (although I haven't verified that), while a local connection does.

In short:

- ensure that Firebird Embedded is correctly deployed together with your application, and
- ensure that Firebird Embedded has the correct bitness for your application.

  That means, for C# x86 or AnyCPU: 32 bit, for x64: 64 bit. Or for AnyCPU, disable 'Prefer 32-bit' in the Program Properties > Build for Platform target: AnyCPU to ensure it loads 64 bit DLLs instead.

The files necessary for a working Firebird 3 Embedded deployment are (quoted from [a blogpost](https://www.lawinegevaar.nl/firebird/jaybird_embedded_example.html) I wrote about using Firebird Embedded from Java):

> ```
> fb
> |--intl
> |  |--fbintl.conf
> |  \--fbintl.dll
> |--plugins
> |  |--engine12.dll
> |  |--fbtrace.dll
> |  |--legacy_auth.dll
> |  |--legacy_usermanager.dll
> |  |--srp.dll
> |  |--udr_engine.conf
> |  \--udr_engine.dll
> |--fbclient.dll
> |--icudt52.dll
> |--icudt52l.dll
> |--icuin52.dll
> \--icuuc52.dll
> ```
>
> The `fb` folder is a trimmed down version of a normal Firebird
>   installation. It is possible that some of the DLLs in the `plugins`
>   folder are not necessary (this may require tweaking `firebird.conf`),
>   and error logging suggests it might be necessary to include
>   `ib_util.dll` as well, but the example program works without it. If
>   you need additional configuration, then you can include a
>   `firebird.conf`.

Contrary to what is shown in the quoted tree, only `engine12.dll` is really required in the `plugins` folder.