# Firebird database in Embedded in C# with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, firebird, firebird-embedded

Can Firebird database be used in embedded mode like SQLite? When working with Entity Framework in SQLite, if I write the database name in the connectionString (example.db), when I run it, a new database is opened in the bin folder. Can I use Firebird the same way?

Or is there a different way to use Firebird without installing its server.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use Firebird Embedded with FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient. In the connection string you must specify `ServerType=1` (or `ServerType = FbServerType.Embedded` when configuring through code), and only specify the path to the database (no host name).

However, to be able to do this, you must include all the necessary binaries for Firebird Embedded in your project *yourself* (or make sure it is on the `PATH` when you run your application).

That is, when you deploy your application, the directory containing your application must contain `fbclient.dll`, `plugins\engine13.dll` (Firebird 4.0, `engine12.dll` for Firebird 3.0) and all required supporting files, or a directory containing those files must be on the `PATH`.

In its simplest form, you can obtain those files by downloading the Firebird 4.0 zipkit of the appropriate bitness from the [Firebird 4.0 download page](https://firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-4-0/). You can optionally remove all the .exe and .bat files, `security4.fdb` and directories `doc`, `examples`, `help`, `include`, `lib`, `misc`, and `system32`, although this still leaves some files that are not strictly necessary.

You may also want to read [Problem connecting to Firebird 3 embedded with C# in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53817952/problem-connecting-to-firebird-3-embedded-with-c-sharp-in-net).

In short, it is possible, but it is not as simple as a SQLite deployment.